# Does the Rails model validate method check the current data as part of the validation process, before the save is attempted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at some RSpec code in Chapter 6 of Michael Hartl's [Rail Tutorial]: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code:validates_uniqueness_of_email_test. It was written to test the uniqueness validation method of the email attribute of the user model.  It looks like this:

Listing 6.18. A test for the rejection of duplicate email addresses. (*spec/models/user_spec.rb*)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  subject { @user }
  .
  .
  .
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

And here is the user model validation code:

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
```

**My question is: How does the validating actually work?**  There is a user with an identical email address already saved into the database and the Rails validation on the @user instance comes back as invalid before I've even tried to save it?  Does the Rails validator use current data to validate instances of the user even if they are just being stored in memory and not currently attempting to be added to the database?

Comment: Why does everybody suddenly start using implicit receivers and subjects in rspec? What's wrong with good ole `it "does something"` and explicit variables? Just ranting. Can't figure out who is the subject in your test? User.new? Or is some code missing? By the way, I regularly check with [Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) it may be of some help to you.

Comment: @ArtShayderov, the author didn't provide this piece of code: `subject { @user }`. You could follow his link to see it yourself.

Comment: Your right, that bit if the code was missing. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`be_valid` calls `valid?` on `@user`. It's how rspec works. And `valid?` calls `run_validations!` which in turn calls `run_callbacks :validate`. You can follow the methods chain through source code: `valid?` is defined in [activerecord / lib / active_record / validations.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb) and it calls `super` `valid?` in  [activemodel / lib / active_model / validations.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.3/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb)

That's about how it works. And the model can be valid or not even if it is unsaved. If it was never saved (`new_record?` returns `true`) as in your case validations on `:create` are called. Basically if model is valid it can be saved. If it was saved (`new_record?` returns `false` but it can contain unsaved changes) validations on `:update` are called.

Comment: This is a good explanation, Art. But just to (perhaps over-) simplify the question and its answer, I want to get at this little bit: "Does the Rails validator use current data to validate [uniqueness]?" 

By definition, to test uniqueness, you need to compare the object to be validated against **existing** objects/records. So, without tracing through the source, I strongly suspect the database (or other object store) **is** being checked during validation (at least for uniqueness, where that would be required by definition).

Comment: Of course it does check the database. Here is a relevant link to Rails docs [3.10 uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness). And you can call `valid?` in your rails console and see SQL query added to your development.log file.